# Rails checkboxes and serialized data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, serialization, checkbox

I'm trying to figure out whats the best way to get checkboxes to properly show their current state.  This is what I have in my form

```
<%= form_for @user, :url => user_notification_preferences_path(@user), :method => :put do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :notification_preferences, @user.notification_preferences do |p| %>

    <%= p.check_box :notify_on_friend_post %>

    <%= p.check_box :notify_on_friend_post %>

    <%= p.check_box :notify_on_friend_request %>

    <%= p.check_box :notify_on_friend_comment %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

notification_preferences is a serialized hash on my user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :notification_preferences, Hash
```

My issue that is no matter what I try, I can not get the check boxes to reflect the existing state of the hash values.  IE, if the hash already contains :notify_on_friend_post => 1, then the check box for that value should be checked.

The form posts the data fine, and I'm able to update my model as well.

Update

using check_box_tag I can get this to work

```
<%= p.hidden_field :notify_on_friend_post, :value => "0" %>
<%= check_box_tag "user[notification_preferences][notify_on_friend_post]", "1", @user.notification_preferences[:notify_on_friend_post] == "1" ? true : false %>
```

ugly but working, still hoping I'm missing something very obvious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
 <%= form_for @user, :url => user_notification_preferences_path(@user), :method => :put do |f| %>

  <%= check_box_tag "user[notification_preferences][]", :notify_on_friend_post, @user.notification_preferences.try(notify_on_friend_post) %>

 <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: closer, updated my answer with what I came up with going down that path

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem and solved it in a simpler way.

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>

  <%= f.fields_for :notifications, @user.notifications do |n| %>
    <%= n.check_box :new_task, checked: @user.notifications[:new_task] == "1" %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

In this way you let the magic of check_box to the work and don't need to have a hidden_field because Rails will provide one for you. Still unsure why you need a "checked" field, but it seemed to not work without one.